# Transparency of oil paints with the passage of time

Tags: optics, visible-light, material-science, scattering, optical-materials

I know that oil paints become transparent after the passage of time (as in the case of many of the Old Masters), because air oxidizes oil, raising its refractive index, so that scattering of light from the pigment particles — which is responsible for humans perceiving the color — is reduced.

But that is the case for whites, yellows and reds. What about black (as in [this picture](https://www.ngv.vic.gov.au/explore/collection/work/3903/), where the white patch below the sitter's left cheek is part of an underlying painting)? Black looks black because it absorbs all the light. So the increasing transparency of black oil paint over time has nothing to do with scattering. What is responsible?

EDIT: In response to one of the comments, I wanted to point out the specific case of carbon black, which is not a mixture of paints. How does that become transparent?

Comment: This article (https://www.artcons.udel.edu/mitra/Documents/MITRA_Mediums_and_Additives.pdf) seems to indicate that change of refractive index has to do less with color but rather chemical composition of the pigments. Since black is often achieved by mixing several pure colors, it appears reasonable that black is equally sensitive to the effect as its constituent pigments.

Comment: @oliver Thank you for your reply. I have updated the question to note the specific case of carbon black.

Comment: @lorenzo Baldessarini Sorry, I could not understand your answer. Could you please explain it again?

Comment: By the way, could it be that your example painting was improperly restaurated?

Comment: Why do you focus on optics? Could the loss of material be at least one of the mechanisms involved in painting becoming transparent (which I also think should be "faded" rather than "transparent")?

Comment: @oliver No, I don't think so. From what I've read (on the Gallery website and elsewhere), this painting does not seem to have been subjected to restoration.

Comment: @Alchimista Sorry, I didn't get it. What do you mean by loss of material? About transparency — the paint is slowly becoming more transparent over time, revealing an underlying painting that was studied in depth [link](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep29594).

Comment: I mean that oil and its content could simply detach even in very minute dust amount over the decades.

Comment: There is no much increased transparency in the black part of the painting. What are you really asking for? I am not a specialist of pigments but surely carbon would have a rather high stability as compared to other pigments. If the oil does not brittle I suspect that black parts of oil painting fade less as compared to colours.

Comment: I am referring to the part of the black dress under her left cheek. In the link in the previous comment, you will see that the white cheek of another portrait lies beneath this area. Compared to the rest of her dress, this region certainly seems whiter, which seems to indicate that the top paint layer is either being chipped off, as you previously suggested, or is becoming increasingly transparent (in which case, I want to know — how?).

Comment: But the question remains, why the black should have faded (if at all) only in the part of the painting you are referring to. What if there was no (carbon) black in that area but something that appeared at the time of creation as a "shade of black", like dark purple for example. Then the different chemical composition would explain why it faded selectively.

Comment: Or, another alternative explanation: the paint fraction in that area could have been improperly mixed by Degas, which caused it to become more sensitive to abrasion.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation, it was written in a hurry. I delete the comment and you may focus on oliver's answers, they should be fine.